# find if xml string node has any child elements or not in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

i have a xml string like the following

```
<parent>
   <id>parent1</id>
   <child>
       <id>parent1child1</id>
   </child>
</parent>
<parent>
   <id>parent2</id>
   <child/>
</parent>
```

how can i check if the child node has more nodes in it using jquery and also one more question is that when i try to get the value of id

```
$(this).find("id").text()
```

then i am getting the id of both parent and child how do i get the id of the present node

Comment: What browsers you need to support?

Comment: You might try `.closest` but it might help if you post a little more of your code.

Comment: @Sanpopo actually my xml is very big and complex so i thought to post a simple one..i am using `$(this).find("id").text()` to get the id of present node...and i am looping through the parent nodes using `$(xml).find('parent').each()` ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you can accomplish this by the following options: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sanpopo/Sncm9/)

```
// gets id for each parent node
$(xml).find('parent > id').each(
function () {
    alert($(this).text());
}); 

// gets id for each child node
$(xml).find('parent > child > id').each(
function () {
    alert($(this).text());   
}); 

// gets count of ids of children in each parent node
$(xml).find('parent').each(
function () {
    alert($(this).find('child > id').length);    
});
```

UPDATE:

```
$(xml).children('parent').each(
    function () {
        //parent id
        alert($(this).children(':first').text());
        $(this).find('child').each(function () {
            //each child element for each parent
            $(this).children(':not(child)').each(function () {
                alert($(this).text());
        });
    });
});
```

[see new fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/sanpopo/xTpWL/)

Comment: what if i have many nodes like id,name,etc..i want to find the values in a single loop of find.each..

Answer (score 0):

You better use xpath for that, but it can as well be done with jquery

```
var xml="<root><parent>\
   <id>parent1</id>\
   <child>\
       <id>parent1child1</id>\
   </child>\
</parent>\
<parent>\
   <id>parent2</id>\
   <child/>\
</parent></root>"
, xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml )
, $xml = $( xmlDoc )
, allWithChildrenId = $xml.find('parent:has(child:has(id))').each(
    function(i,e) {  console.log (i,e) })
, allWithChildrenAny = $xml.find('parent:has(child:has(*))').each(
    function(i,e) {  console.log (i,e) })
```